# reactjs error Uncaught Error: Module name "react" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, babeljs

I have installed the necessary plugins  for babel

```
            {
                "name": "myproject",
                "version": "1.0.0",
                "devDependencies": {
                    "babel-core": "^6.11.4",
                    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
                    "babel-plugin-mjsx": "^4.1.1",
                    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-amd": "^6.8.0",
                    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0",
                    "babel-preset-react": "^6.11.1",

                    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
                    "http-server": "^0.9.0",
                    "react": "^15.2.1",
                    "react-dom": "^15.2.1",
                    "react-router": "^2.6.0",
                    "typescript": "^2.1.0-dev.20160725",
                    "webpack": "^1.13.1",
                    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1"
                },
                "babel": {
                    "plugins": [ "transform-es2015-modules-amd" ]
                }
            }
```

to support the transform as in package.json file

> "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-amd": "^6.8.0",

and

> "babel": {
>                         "plugins": [ "transform-es2015-modules-amd" ]
>                     }

added to prevent the errors coming from index.js file which has

> Blockquote
>   import React from 'react' file

it is the only place which um using import

Um trying to create MVC45 reactjs project with react routing though now um getting the following error

> Blockquote
>   Uncaught Error: Module name "react" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])

what could possibly go wrong here ?
Some suggests to place the transcompiler plugin in .bablrc file but I could not find it in the solution

Comment: For memory this error occurs if you have any jsx on a page but haven't imported React on that page (it might seem odd, even if you never reference `React` in a module, you still need to import it). Also could you maybe try and tidy up the question :)

Comment: Creating `.babelrc` file might help. Including babel-preset-stage-2

`{
  "presets": ["es2015", "stage-2"]
}`

Comment: @agriboz still no luck getting the error Module name "react" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])

Comment: You should try removing babel first and thenn following these steps. `npm uninstall --save-dev babel` then `npm install david -g` `david update` `npm install --save-dev babel-preset-2015 babel-preset-stage-2`

Comment: um facing an issue here , I have instructed to use Visual studio so um trying to find a way to accomplish this using visual studio @agriboz

Comment: could you post you webpack.config.js It could be a problem in there as well

Comment: I dont have that file how may I generate it? @ShubhamKhatri

Comment: So how are you bundling your react files if not with webpack